# 3-variable linear model in R

Tags: r, model, regression, lm

I want to get coefficients for a linear model related to synergism/antagonism between different chemicals.

Chemicals X, Y, Z.  Coefficients b0...b7.

0 = b0 + b1x + b2y + b3z + b4xy + b5xz + b6yz + b7xyz

Some combination of X, Y, Z will kill 50% of cells (b0 represents this total effectiveness), and the sign/magnitude of the higher order terms represents interactions between chemicals.

Given real datapoints, I want to fit this model.

EDIT: I've gotten rid of the trivial solution by adding a forcing value at the start.  Test data:

```
x1 <- c(0,1,2,3,4)
y1 <- c(0,2,1,5,4)
z1 <- c(0,1,-0.66667,-6,-7.25)

q <- c(-1,0,0,0,0)

model <- lm(q ~ x1*y1*z1)
```

This set has coefficients: -30, 12, 6, 4, 1, -1, 0, 0.5

EDIT: Progress made from before, will try some more data points.  The first four coefficients look good (multiply by 30):

```
Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           y1           z1        x1:y1        x1:z1        y1:z1     x1:y1:z1  
   -1.00000      0.47826      0.24943      0.13730     -0.05721           NA           NA           NA
```

EDIT: Adding more data points hasn't been successful so far, not sure if I need to have a certain minimum amount to be accurate.

Am I setting things up ccorrectly?  Once I have coefficents, I want to solve for z so that I can plot a 3D surface.  Thanks!

Comment: Given the small sample size, it seems quite hard to estimate 3 variables interaction

Comment: Do you feel like you issue is about Statistics (how to determine this properly) or the Programming (you know what you want to do, just no how to do it right)? If it's the former, then you'll likely get a better response asking on [stats.se]

Comment: @YacineHajji I can do a larger set of points to test.  The real scenario will have maybe ~10-20 points?

Comment: @divibisan Definitely a programming thing.  I don't think the model I'm using is particularly complicated, just confused on setup.

Comment: @threadofmotion You are trying to estimate a three-way interaction here (which definately comprises a complex model term). You will need lots and lots of data points in order to obtain stable estimates of your regression coefficients in this case. This is never going to work out well for merely 10-20 points... Use as a rule of thumb ~10-15 data points per _main effect_. For a two-way interaction, you will need a whole lot more and for a three-way interaction, oh well.....

Comment: @DionGroothof We could collect more, so you'd want ~70 points for 7 effects?  One thing to keep in mind though is that for basic research, large error bars are okay, and there is going to be other noise (both in vitro and in situ).  Even if we have no idea of exact magnitude of the coefficient, just being confident in the sign is worth reporting.

Comment: The dependent value (i.e. "q") are all zeros.  The only way to obtain all zeros with 3 independent values is for the coefficients to also be zero.  Try this will a larger dataset and more realistic values and ask a new question.  By the way, 3 independent variables and 1 dependent variable is a 4D surface.

Comment: @Dave2e I defined that test data with those nonzero coefficients I provided.  Anyway, what I was trying to get at is I wasn't sure how to set up the dependent variable to model those points.  If I try x, y, or z it will of course return 1:1 and zeros for the rest.  If I try a constant, zero or otherwise, same result.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Are you trying to perform a linear regression or solve for an unknown?  The model is correct for to the linear regression, except you are lacking enough data to find an unique fit.

Comment: @Dave2e Actually, your earlier comment gave me an idea.  If I simply include add an extra value of -1:  (-1,0,0,0...) with a zero value for x/y/z, it forces the trivial solution to be excluded.  This gets me close (I'm getting good values for the first four coefficients) but I will see if I can get 5-7 with more data points.

Comment: @DionGroothof  I was able to get 4/7 coefficients with 4 points, and get all 7 with 16 points.  Just needed to kick the trivial value.  Of course, with noisy real data it may be more or less, will have to test more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the coefficients using just 16 arbitrary data points, and appending a point to exclude the trivial answer:

```
x1 <- c(0,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
y1 <- c(0,2,1,5,4,3,7,5,8,6,2,1,5,5,3,5,7)
z1 <- c(0,1,-0.66667,-6,-7.25,-0.66667,-5.55556,-6,-6.125,-4,-2.5,-6,-6.8,-7.3913,-11.1429,-8.2069,-6.83333)

q <- c(-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

model <- lm(q ~ x1*y1*z1)
```